# Mvc area routing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-routing, area

Area folders look like :

```
Areas 
    Admin
        Controllers
            UserController
            BranchController
            AdminHomeController
```

Project directories look like :

```
Controller
    UserController
        GetAllUsers
```

area route registration

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { controller = "Branch|AdminHome|User" }
    );
}
```

project route registration

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new string[] { "MyApp.Areas.Admin.Controllers" });
}
```

When I route like this: `http://mydomain.com/User/GetAllUsers` I get resource not found error (404). I get this error after adding UserController to Area.

How can I fix this error?

Thanks...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You've messed up your controller namespaces.

Your main route definition should be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "MyApp.Controllers" }
);
```

And your Admin area route registration should be:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { controller = "Branch|AdminHome|User" },
        new[] { "MyApp.Areas.Admin.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

Notice how the correct namespaces should be used.

Comment: I've been confused by the namespaces that correspond to the areas. In this example the namespace MyApp.Areas.Admin.Controllers matches the folder hierarchy however namespace definition is arbitrary right? Meaning the programmer could assign any namespace to the controller class that they wanted - I thought. Or is there some asp.net mvc convention that requires he namespace to match the folder hierarchy?

Comment: @Howiecamp the default behaviour of Visual Studio is to match the namespace to the folder hierarchy and that is what you will typically see in all .net projects (not just MVC projects).

Answer (score 4):

An up to date solution for ASP.NET Core MVC.

```
[Area("Products")]
public class HomeController : Controller
```

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/areas