# Adding MVC Application under another MVC application in IIS

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have two separated MVC applications and I want to deploy one of them under another one. I created a web site and an application in the ISS like "testsite1" and "testsite2". **local.testsite1** is working very well but **local.testsite1/testsite2** is not working because testsite1 is catching the request and trying to find a controller and throwing an exception. I do not want to create two different web site in IIS. How can I fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`local.testsite1` and `local.testsite1/testsite2` are the same domains. Not a sub-domain. Which means the application/IIS looking for the controller is the right behavior.

You may consider merging the sites in to one and use MVC Area to separate them? Also if you do not merge the site how will you Fire the app_start and other events separately for the sites?

In that case you can write custom routes separating the routes of **testsite2** from **testsite1**.

For example route definition for testsite1 can be:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
    namespaces: new string[] { "YourApp.Controllers" }
);
```

And your testsite2 area route registration can be:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Admin_default",
        "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        new { controller = "Branch|AdminHome|User" },
        new[] { "YourApp.Areas.testsite2.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

More about the implementation is here: [Mvc area routing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616240/mvc-area-routing)

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the second website as an application within the test site 1 in IIS.

To do that, right click the website for the first MVC application in IIS, click `Add Application...`, set an alias, the pool you want to use, and the path of the second MVC application's files.

[image: Highlighted Add Application option]